# How to sort a f.select?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= f.select(:company_id, Company.all.collect {|company| [company.name, company.id]}) %>
```

How can i sort this from A-Z?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect{|company| [company.name, company.id]}.sort_by{|a, b| a} %>
```

Or

```
<%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect{|company| [company.name, company.id]}.sort{|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]} %>
```

**UPD**

Or just `<%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }.sort %>` – Phrogz

Comment: Or just `<%= f.select(:company_id, Company.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }.sort %>`

Comment: how come select doesn't need a closing ")" ? (sorry I'm completely new to ruby)

Comment: @Jan it needs, it's a typo